# Webpack code splitting utilizing react-router jsx

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, jsx, code-splitting

My routes are mapped with jsx. I use webpack to bundle stuff and I would like to split the output js file into chunks according to the routes.

I tried require.ensure but webpack doesn't split anything. At the end it only generates one bundle file. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I don't want to maintain 2 places where the routes live. Ideally webpack uses my already defined routes.

```
export const renderRoutes = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path='en' component={AppContainer}>
      <Route path='cart' getComponent={(location, cb) => {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
          cb(null, require('./Cart/CartContainer'));
         });
       }}/>
        <Route path='checkout'>
          <Route path='shipping_address' component={ShippingAddressFormContainer} />
          <Route path='delivery_options' component={DeliveryOptionFormContainer} />
          <Route path='payment' component={PaymentContainer} />
          <Route path='review_order' component={ReviewOrderContainer} />
          <Route path='confirmation' component={ConfirmationContainer} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

render(
  renderRoutes(),
  document.getElementById('react-root')
);
```

gruntfile config:

```
dev: {
        entry: [
          './<%= paths.src %>/javascripts/react/containers/Root'
        ],
        output: {
          path: path.join(__dirname, '<%= paths.dist %>/javascripts'),
          filename: 'bundle.js',
          chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
          publicPath: '/en/'
        },
        devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
        plugins: [
          new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('bundle.js'),
          new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(), // Chunk ids by occurrence count. Ids that are used often get lower (shorter) ids.
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
              'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
          })
        ],
        module: {
          preLoaders: [
            {
              test: /\.json$/,
              loader: 'json'
            },
          ],
          loaders: [
            {
              test: /\.js$/,
              loaders: ['babel'],
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              include: __dirname
            }
          ]
        }
      },
```

dev task output

```
        Asset     Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js  2.76 MB  0, 1, 0  [emitted]  bundle.js, main
bundle.js.map  3.17 MB  0, 1, 0  [emitted]  bundle.js, main
```

I read a few tutorials but it seems this case is not so common.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, please, update your question with more information. Something like if there are errors. What are the build steps. Have you checked your build folder? I'm asking this because I tried to reproduce, and I was able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for having a look! I'm not getting any errors with the updated code. Do you reckon I should use require.ensure on all the routes? I would have expected that it would have chunked at least once when doing the require.ensure on the cart path.

Comment: That's so strange. One more question, is `./<%= paths.src %>/javascripts/react/containers/Root` your "main" file? Btw, you can split only the routes that you want/need, in my test, it produced one more chunk, for one route only.

Comment: Did you update your code? Your first code was using `getComponent` (which is correct).

Comment: yes Root.js is my main file where the routes are located. Aha so i need to do the require.ensure on all the routes I want a chunk of?

Comment: I updated back to getcomponent but still just get bundle.js out.

Comment: webpack is not giving me any errros but when actually loading the page it says "ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128077/discussion-between-william-martins-and-lhtdesign).

Comment: ok that error i fixed with `new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('main', 'bundle.js')` but seems like the page is not rendering the cart now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I talked to OP in chat, he showed me his entire code and I figured it out!

In your code, you have something like that:

```js
// ... Some imports here
import CartContainer from './Cart/CartContainer';
// ... More imports here

export const renderRoutes = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            // Some other routes here
            <Route path='cart' getComponent={(location, cb) => {
                require.ensure([], (require) => {
                    cb(null, require('./Cart/Container').default);
                });
            }} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);
```

Now you may see it, but you're "tricking" webpack, because, when you `import CartContainer` (in the first lines), you're saying "ok, this chunk (the main) has `CartContainer`, please, add it to the bundle". Then, when you use `require.ensure`, webpack already knows that this dependency is loaded (it went to main chunk) and it doesn't need to split this into a different chunk.

You just need to remove the first import, so webpack will know that you want `CartContainer` in a separate chunk! Just note that, since you're using `babel`, you'll need to add `.default` when requiring this extra chunk.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This was it! Thanks for your persistence and help!